# pySpark dataframe data insert in to Hive table

Tags: hive, pyspark

I have a requirement to create a final dataframe after applying mapping conditions.
For Ex. if I have the final dataframe like below

```
df.show()
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|c  |2  |
+---+---+
printSchema:
  a: string (nullable - true)
  b: integer (nullable - true)
```

I have to load the final table into Hive table with same columns but with different schema where some of the column values doesn't accept null values.
For example, if in above dataframe if column 'a' has any null value it should not update the particular row in hive table.
i'm using below command to write into table -

```
df.write.mode(append).format(parquet).saveAsTable(table_name)
```

So, shall I the change schema before proceed with the table append ??

```
schema = StructType([StructField("a", StringType, False), ("b", IntegerType(), True)])
df_updated = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema)
```

Comment: What do you mean by should not update the row in hive? You're doing an append not a merge.

Comment: I dont want to have null records in specified columns of dataframe before loading it to hive table.

Comment: Why don't you just filter the dataframe before you save it? `df = df.filter(df.col_X. isNotNull())`